Blank pages after RollingUpdate for web deployment
We have a webserver based on Django+Gunicorn that is running in a kubernetes deployment. When we deploy a new version, we use RollingUpdate strategy. Any client that was connected to the webserver before the deployment gets a blank page. we suspect this could be due to an issue that is caused by browser cache, because it does seem to get resolved with a hard refresh.
Is there a way to force refresh or store the cache in a different way so it won't impact the clients when we update the pods? any other suggestion will also be greatly appreciated
